# Grid columns and rows in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I have 30 items in comboBox. I'm looking for the way to add columns and rows in a combobox.

Here is what I want to do:

[image]

The combobox have 4 columns, 7 rows (row = itemCount/columns).

**Item class:**

```
public class ItemSymbol{
   public string ImageName{
     get; set;
   }

   public string Comment{
     get; set;
   }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
List<ItemSymbol> lstsymbol=new List<ItemSymbol>(30){
  new ItemSymbol(){ImageName=@"Resources\bunny.png",Comment="funny"},
  new ItemSymbol(){ImageName=@"Resources\hand.png",Comment="communication"},
  new ItemSymbol(){ImageName=@"Resources\heart1.png",Comment="love"},
  new ItemSymbol(){ImageName=@"Resources\heart2.png",Comment="love"}
};
```

**Window1.xaml:**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbo" 
 ItemsSource="{Binding lstsymbol}" 
 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
 <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
     <Image Width="30" Height="30"
      Source="{Binding ImageRes}" Margin="5" ToolTip="{Binding Comment}"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this element to your Combobox in XAML:

```
<ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <UniformGrid Rows="7" Columns="4" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
```

(But you know that 7x4 is less then 30?) :-)

Comment: yes,I know that.thank!it is working.How to adjust width height of uniform to fit with content in it@Fratyx

Comment: Do you mean the screen size of the UnformGrid or the number of rows and columns.

Comment: I tried to set  MaxDropDownHeight="Auto". But nothing.

Comment: Hm. Don't know. Dropdown size should automatically adapt to UniformGrid size.

Comment: I have added UniformGrid Rows="{Binding list.Count/columnNum.vote +1.Thank again!@Fratyx